# O que é devops?

Tags: terminologia, arquitetura-de-software

Gostaria de saber o que é "devops" na prática. Sinceramente gostaria de saber uma experiência ao invés de uma definição formal.

Comment: Tirei a parte da pergunta que pede uma opinião porque isso abre espaço pra respostas baseadas somente em achismos e sem embasamento concreto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu gosto muito de uma definição que eu recebi de uma entrevista que eu fiz. O objetivo da cultura devops parece ser, no final das contas, otimizar o ciclo de vida do software.

Isso envolve criar rotinas automatizadas para que o fluxo desde o dev até a produção seja mais eficiente e rápida. Não apenas automatização, mas controle da qualidade do código, o que evita "bounces" e tempo desperdiçado. Alias, eu acho muito legal estudar um pouco sobre Kaizen junto com a filosofia devops. Agile vai entrar na gama de conhecimento de um analista devops, além das ferramentas de pipeline, qualidade de código, automatização, infra-as-code, além de observabilidade.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 20):

Do artigo da Wikipedia em Português (editado):

> DevOps (amálgama do termo em inglês ***Dev***elopment and **Op**eration**s**, desenvolvimento e operações) é uma metodologia de desenvolvimento de software que explora a comunicação, colaboração e integração entre desenvolvedores de software e outros profissionais de TI (Tecnologia da Informação). DevOps é a reação à interdependência entre desenvolvimento de software e operações de TI. Pretende ajudar organizações a produzir software e serviços rapidamente.

Implementações atuais dessa metodologia se baseiam tanto em um conjunto de processos e métodos cobrindo comunicação e colaboração entre departamentos de desenvolvimento, QA (garantia de qualidade) e operações de TI quanto processos de automatização de entrega de software (*deploy*) e mudanças de infra-estrutura

Em algumas organizações, essa colaboração envolve incorporar especialistas de operações de TI em equipes de desenvolvimento de software, formando uma equipe multifuncional que também pode ser combinada com o gerenciamento de matrizes.

Fonte: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps

Comment: No começo você menciona a Wikipedia PT, mas depois colocou o link da Wikipedia EN? Fiquei confuso sobre sua fonte

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado *good catch*, mencionei um mas colei outro. Corrigido!

Answer (score 16):

Do Artigo da AWS (https://aws.amazon.com/pt/devops/):

> O DevOps é a combinação de filosofias culturais, práticas e ferramentas que aumentam a capacidade de uma empresa de distribuir aplicativos e serviços em alta velocidade: otimizando e aperfeiçoando produtos em um ritmo mais rápido do que o das empresas que usam processos tradicionais de desenvolvimento de software e gerenciamento de infraestrutura. Essa velocidade permite que as empresas atendam melhor aos seus clientes e compitam de modo mais eficaz no mercado.

Exemplos de ferramentas: Controle de versão, automação do código para deployments, configuration management, ticketing systems, monitoramento e provisionamento.

Answer (score 12):

**DevOps** sigla para *Development and Operations*, que seria em português **Des**envolvimento de **Op**erações tem como idealização a integração contínua, agilidade, qualidade, estabilidade com escalabilidade e elasticidade; considerando está diretamente relacionado a um melhor feedback entre as áreas de TI. A imagem exemplifica melhor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O termo **DevOps** foi "inventado" para descrever uma cultura que abriga tanto profissionais de desenvolvimento de software quanto de operações (*[sysadmin](https://www.4linux.com.br/noticias/2014/sysadmin-e-sysadmins-que-valem-por-1000)*). A chave está na colaboração entre essas duas equipes e tem basicamente quatro eixos principais: cultura, automação, avaliação e compartilhamento.

> Um ambiente fundamentado pela cultura DevOps ajuda as empresas a
>   produzirem software e serviços de forma mais ágil. Em outras palavras,
>   gera aumento de produtividade e redução de custos.

<sup>**Referências**</sup>

- [O que é DevOps afinal?](http://gutocarvalho.net/octopress/2013/03/16/o-que-e-um-devops-afinal/)
- [DevOps: Conceitos e características](http://www.devmedia.com.br/devops-conceitos-e-caracteristicas/32030)